# Dynamic div displayed using innerHTML overlaps the exisitng static content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a static header fixed on top of the page inside a `div1`. Below I have another empty `div2`, followed by another `div3` where I show some data.

On click of a button in `div3`, I'm trying to show some content using `innerHTML`.
This is working fine. But the problem is I want the `div2` also to be fixed on top next to `div1` so that even when the page is scrolled it's not affected.

When I give CSS position as fixed, `div2` overlaps `div3`. With position as static, it does not overlap `div3` but it's scrollable and not fixed.

Code is something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="panel"></div>
<div>Content</div>
```

**JS:**

On click of button

```
var panel = document.getElementById('panel');
panel.innerHTML = "<div>Hello World</div>";
```

**CSS:**

```
#header {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 200;
    position: fixed;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0F4DBC', endColorstr='#00A9E0', GradientType=1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0F4DBC, #00A9E0);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #0F4DBC, #00A9E0);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #0F4DBC, #00A9E0);
}
```

So how do I solve this?

Comment: First, panel.innerHTML = "Hello World" is what you need (not "<div>Hello World</div>"), by the way, the css, here, can be the problem, thus pls, post  it

Comment: your panel should be in quotes `document.getElementById('panel');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed positioning is similar to absolute positioning, with the exception that the element's containing block is the viewport. So, whenever you give `position: fixed`, it's immediate next sibling element must contain `padding-top/margin-top` equivalent to the `height` of the `fixed` positioned element.

In your case, you have to give `padding-top/margin-top` to `#panel` equivalent to the `height` of the `#header`.

**Code Snippet**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <style>

    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #header {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0f4dbc, #00a9e0);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #0f4dbc, #00a9e0);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #0f4dbc, #00a9e0);
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0f4dbc', endColorstr='#00a9e0', GradientType=1);
      color: #fff;
      height: 30px;
      left: 0;
      line-height: 30px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 200;
    }

    #panel {
      /*padding-top: 30px;*/
      margin-top: 30px;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="panel"></div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <script>
    // var panel = document.querySelector('#panel');
    var panel = document.getElementById('panel');
    panel.innerHTML = "<div>Hello World</div>";
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This will do the trick.

> It is better to wrap your `#panel` & `div` containing `Content` in a
>   separate `#contentWrapper` to separate it from the `fixed` positioned
>   element. You can then give `padding-top/margin-top` to
>   `#contentWrapper`.
>
> In your case, this will help if your `innerHTML` is set on any
>   `event (Click, etc)` trigger as `#panel` won't contain any data until
>   the event is triggered & hence `div` with `Content` will not **overlap** 
>   with `fixed` positioned element as it is wrapped in `#contentWrapper`
>   with `padding-top/margin-top`.
>
> **CSS**
>
> ```
> #contentWrapper {
>   /*padding-top: 30px;*/
>   margin-top: 30px;
> }
> ```
>
> **HTML**
>
> ```
> <div id="header">Header</div>
> <div id="contentWrapper">
>   <div id="panel"></div>
>   <div>Content</div>
> </div>
> ```

You can refer [Mozilla/position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to better understand the concept.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If this helped & you think is the right answer, please **accept** as the **answer**. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making div 1 and 2 fixed. try this:

```
<div style="position:fixed">
  <div>Header</div>
  <div id="panel"></div>
</div>
<div>Content</div>
```

This means your second div will move with the header as they are contained in a div that has fixed position.

Comment: It's still getting overlapped. As it appears dynamically on click of button.